# Mongo result set with multiple memberIds

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using Meteor/Mongo with Typescript/Javascript.

I have a chat app I am developing. I get a result set from Mongo.

```
const chats: Mongo.Cursor<Chat> = Chats.find(
  { memberIds: 'J65'},
  {
    sort: { lastMessageCreatedAt: -1 },
    transform: this.transformChat.bind(this),
    fields: { memberIds: 1, lastMessageCreatedAt: 1 } 
  }
);
```

This returns the Chats for J65 .

**Question**

Is it possible to have multiple memberIds? i.e. return the results for more than one matching id

**More info**

I have tried this with no success, i.e. it returns nothing even though there is a match (no errors though).

```
let registeredIds: String[] = ['J65', 'J66'];
...
{ memberIds: registeredIds },
```

this is what is in the database:

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "_id": "CHb8FSuGSfZMPhkrW",
>     "memberIds": [
>       "P9",
>       "J64"
>     ]
>   },
>   {
>     "_id": "uMSJjHheTp7RhGdH3",
>     "memberIds": [
>       "P9",
>       "J65"
>     ]
>   },
>   {
>     "_id": "e6ZMmRaJLPptF63z8",
>     "memberIds": [
>       "P9",
>       "J66"
>     ]
>   }
> ]
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `$in` operator.

Your code shall look like:

```
const chats: Mongo.Cursor<Chat> = Chats.find(
  { memberIds: {$in:['J65','J66','J67']},
  {
    sort: { lastMessageCreatedAt: -1 },
    transform: this.transformChat.bind(this),
    fields: { memberIds: 1, lastMessageCreatedAt: 1 } 
  }
);
```

Refer [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) for more information.